# php date format regex check

Tags: php, regex, date

i am trying to valdiate the date field "`YYYYMMDD`" using PHP regex. I tried something like this

```
/([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/
```

but in this one, it's going to accept any two digits like 01-99 for MM or DD, but i am looking to have something for 01-12 for MM and 01-31 for DD. Any advise on doing this?

thanks

Comment: Probably need to add some PHP code for validation also

Comment: Regexes are NOT the way to valid dates, except in the grossest way (e.g. "it's all digits"). '2011-02-29' would get accepted, even though that's not valid date as 2011 isn't a leapyear.

Comment: @all, i agree with the reasons, will write a php fucntion. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of *regular expressions* you can also split the string and use **[`checkdate`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php)** to see if the date is valid.

Comment: how would i split 20091010 into 3 parts? i don't have any delimiter, should i go with counting the digits and split it?

Comment: If you're sure you have `YYYYMMDD` you can use `substr()`.

Comment: thanks, i did this way and it worked. thanks all. how would i put my sample  code here? is it [code] tabg?

Answer (score 4):

This should do the job:

```
function dateValidate($date) {
    $t = strtotime($date);
    return date('Ymd', $t) == $date;
}
```

**edit:** Worth noting that this won't be as fast as a regexp but in terms of noticeable performance will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Regex doesn't seem very practical for date validation. Why not split it into pieces, then use `checkdate()`?

Answer (score 0):

For the month, you could use:

```
(0[1-9]|1[012])
```

For days:

```
(0[1-9]| [12][0-9]|3[01])
```

Some good examples [here](http://www.roscripts.com/PHP_regular_expressions_examples-136.html).

Comment: What about months shorter than 31 days/leap years etc.? IMHO full validation would be too cumbersome to do with *regexp* only.

Comment: True, shorter versions wont work... given format was `YYYYMMDD`.

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT USE checkdate as checkdate('1\'', '1', '2000') validates TRUE.